# jQuery .error jqXHR.responseText is empty

Tags: jquery

I have a Java Spring MVC controller that can throw an exception.  I have an @ExceptionHandler setup to handle these errors, and I'd like to use it to return the exception's message to the caller.

The server code is:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(DeviceException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleException(DeviceException ex)   {
      return ex.getMessage();
    }
```

I have tested throwing a DeviceException and getting the result using Curl from the CLI, the exception's message is being returned in the response body.  I can't get the jQuery .error handler to display it however, my handler code is:

```
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // problem, the data is always blank
              alert('jqXHR.responseText = ', jqXHR.responseText);
            }
```

All I ever get for the responseText is an empty string.  How do I get the string returned by the @ExceptionHandler to display in the jQuery error handler?

Comment: I am annoyed it's so hard to fix this basic problem, I'll take any help I can get no matter how random :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. jqXHR.responseText is set in chrome but not FF 3.6.  I'm POSTING 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and getting back 'application/json' - is that breaking the protocol?

Comment: Can you post the complete HTTP response?

Comment: December 2016 (Firefox 50.1.0). Still same problem. textStatus returns 'error', errorThrown seems empty, and so does jqXHR.responseText. Probably something really lame I'm doing...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var msg = '<div style="padding:20px;">';
msg += "We're sorry, there was an error during your request.  Please refresh the page, then try again.  If your problem persists, please contact technical support. <br /><br /> <b>Cause:</b> <br /> ";
switch (textStatus) {
    case ('timeout'):
        msg += 'Request timed out.';
        break;
    case ('error'):
        msg += 'Error status returned.';
        break;
    case ('abort'):
        msg += 'Request was aborted.';
        break;
    case ('parseerror'):
        msg += 'There was an error parsing your request.';
        break;
    default:
        msg += 'No status returned.';
        break;
}
$(this).html(msg + ' <br /><br /> ' + errorThrown + ' <br /></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and strangely it was fixed by switching that project to use IIS Express in Visual Studio 2012.